# I need to horizontally center a ul but using position:absolute, left and transform is causing a weird behaviour on width/margin

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm working on the language nav of a simple multi-lingual webpage.
On large view-ports everything works but as soon as we reduce the size of the view-port something weird happens to the width or margins, not sure which one is affected as none of them should be defined but something is definitely interfering.

edit: The weird behavior is that the ul starts breaking of way too soon. It seems to be breaking when it's wider than 50% of the parent instead of the regular 100%. What's causing it is the left and the transform. The position and bottom work as expected.

It's easier if I just show it so I made a fiddle, just compact the view-port and you'll see:

http://jsfiddle.net/ricardojcmarques/vrfvjmdr/

Apparently I need to post code so here goes the html:

```
<ul id="languageHolder">
    <li class="ColumnDevider">
        <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="2px" height="1px" viewBox="0 0 2 1">
             <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#000000" width="2" height="1"></rect>
         </svg>
    </li>
    <li class="Column">
        <a class="button" id="pt">Português</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ColumnDevider">
        <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="2px" height="1px" viewBox="0 0 2 1">
             <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#000000" width="2" height="1"></rect>
        </svg>
    </li>
    <li class="Column">
        <a class="button" id="es">Español</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ColumnDevider">
        <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="2px" height="1px" viewBox="0 0 2 1">
             <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#000000" width="2" height="1"></rect>
        </svg>
    </li>
    <li class="Column">
        <a class="button" id="de">Deutsch</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ColumnDevider">
        <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="2px" height="1px" viewBox="0 0 2 1">
             <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#000000" width="2" height="1"></rect>
        </svg>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the css:

```
html,body,div,h1,h2,p,a,img,ul,li,form,label{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
    font-size: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
}

body{
    line-height: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: ##000000;
    padding:0;
    margin:30px
}

a:visited{
    color:#000000;
}

ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#languageHolder{
    list-style: none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:30px;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#languageHolder li{
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    height:18px;
}

.Column{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"PTSans_Regular";
    margin:0 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.ColumnDevider{
    background-color:#000000;
    background:#000000;
}
```

I have no clue what to try more. Any and all suggestions are welcome. Thanks ahead.

ps: The objective is to keep the width dynamic because the display languages are dynamically displayed depending on a few factors, and more languages can be added in the future.

Comment: What does "something weird happens" mean? Please clarify what is happening that you don't like and what *should* happen at smaller viewport widths.

Comment: The li's start to break of too soon. Something seems to be defining ether width for the UL that's 50% or something of the sort. The ul should maintain a single line until the viewport is smaller than it is. (I also have a small margin arond the body on the final page as well, but the behavior also happens here independent from that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if we understand each other, but "something weird happend" means that the line start breaking, right?

So, there are some stuff to simplify first - you don't need any deviders, use border for the `li` tags.

```
<ul id="languageHolder">
    <li>
        <a class="button" id="pt">Português</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="button" id="es">Español</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="button" id="de">Deutsch</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and than just change the css (I've used yours, the very last untouched css is for "ul")

```
#languageHolder{
    list-style: none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:30px;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
     width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#languageHolder li{
    height:18px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"PTSans_Regular";
    padding:0 10px; 
    cursor:pointer;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
}
#languageHolder li:first-child{
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

@media (max-width: 200px){ /*small sizes = set your "small size"*/
    #languageHolder li{
        border-left:0px !important;
        border-right:0px;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Media query helps you to custimize css for some width/height specific cases, in your case it's too narrow. Right now border disappears and items are not floating anymore, so one is placed bellow another.

Here you go with JSFIDDLE (updated): http://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/pkeepkgd/2/

Comment: Yeah the problem is that the ul starts breaking off too soon. It seems to be breaking when 50% of the viewport is smaller than the ul. But that doesn't make any sense. I want to find a way to stop it breaking at at 50% and use 100% like normal. I don't understand what's making the ul behave like that. I know what's causing it is the left and transform i set on them, just the absolute and bottom positioning work as expected.

Comment: Hm, it's because left: 50%; so the ul element takes only 50% width of screen, I'm on my way, I'll try to fix it when I'll be at home.

Comment: here you go: #languageHolder li{display: inline-block;} instead of float:left, and set the ul width to 100% I'm going to update the code

Comment: That seems to have done the job thank you very much. But in any case I wish someone could explain what was limiting the width of the ul while using the float left in conjunction with this particular positioning.

Answer (score 1):

The point about CSS transforms are that they are *visual* changes...they don't actually change the physical position of the element.

As such, although the element is visually in the middle the browser remembers where it actually is and when the left side reaches the parent's edge the line breaks start appearing.

To combat this you should disable the line breaking by adding `white-space:nowrap;` to the `ul`.

I would also switch out the floats for `inline-block` and then hide the "border" `li` as they won't break nicely.

Then use media queries (as required) to break the `li` into a column.

```css
html,body,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: ##000000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px
}
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: lightblue;
}
#languageHolder {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#languageHolder li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  height: 18px;
}
.Column {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "PTSans_Regular";
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ColumnDevider {
  background-color: #000000;
  background: #000000;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #languageHolder li {
    display: block;
  }
  #languageHolder li.ColumnDevider {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="languageHolder">
  <li class="ColumnDevider">
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="2px" height="1px" viewBox="0 0 2 1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#000000" width="2" height="1"></rect>
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li class="Column"> <a class="button" id="pt">Português</a>

  </li>
  <li class="ColumnDevider">
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="2px" height="1px" viewBox="0 0 2 1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#000000" width="2" height="1"></rect>
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li class="Column"> <a class="button" id="es">Español</a>

  </li>
  <li class="ColumnDevider">
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="2px" height="1px" viewBox="0 0 2 1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#000000" width="2" height="1"></rect>
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li class="Column"> <a class="button" id="de">Deutsch</a>

  </li>
  <li class="ColumnDevider">
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="2px" height="1px" viewBox="0 0 2 1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#000000" width="2" height="1"></rect>
    </svg>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrfvjmdr/4/)